# WiX Custom Action - build failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to build the sample WiX Custom action using C#. I have created the TestCustomActions project using 'C# Custom Action Project' template in VS 2015 Community edition.

I am not able to build it. It keeps throwing the following error -

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3832,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\TestCustomActions\obj\x86\Release\TestCustomActions.CA.dll" because it was not found.

Looks like, unmanaged CA.dll is not getting generated. Any idea, what could be the problem?

Comment: looks like you have at least one locale being generated (or expected to be generated).  But, hard to tell without more detail.  All sorts of reasons why a dependent file isn't being found.

Comment: @PeterRitchie, This is what VS shows in error and output. How to get the more details?

Comment: Did you use the wix c# project template or a normal C# project template?

Comment: WIX C# Project template only.

Comment: I am able to generate the ca.dll using MakeSfxCA.exe. So, looks like some issue through VS only.

Comment: Does your csproj file import `Wix.CA.targets`?

Comment: @BrianSutherland, yes. I believe, you are talking in project file.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out, at least for me, it was the AutoSandbox of Comodo.
Make VisualStudio and MakeSfxCA.exe run outside the sandbox and the build works.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16095930)

Comment: As I found out, at least for me, it was the AutoSandbox of Comodo. Make VisualStudio and MakeSfxCA.exe run outside the sandbox and the build works.